# How to get a C++ vector out of const float*

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, constants

I am using a library which has a function which returns a `const float *`.

How can I get a normal vector out of that, to find out the size and other info?

I tried doing *array, but this did not work.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Ask the author.

Comment: I don't believe you can recover the size when i'ts decayed to a pointer. Some libraries would offer an `end` check function so you can loop over stuff - we'd need more info on the function prototypes to answer. It might be quicker to ask the libarary implementor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't find the size of the array the pointer points to. The function has to return the size somehow or the size is fixed and documented.

Answer (score 2):

A `const float *` is a pointer. Assuming it points to anything, the pointer points to a `float` object. That `float` object might or might not be an element of an array. The documentation of the function that returns the pointer might have information about the pointer.

> How to get an array/vector out of const float*

It depends very much on what do you mean by "get an array/vector". If the pointer does point to an element of an array, then from certain perspective, you can "get the array" (or rather, a pointer to the array) by calling the function that returns the pointer.

If by "get the array/vector", you mean get a reference to the array object, and the pointer points to the first element of that array, then that is certainly possible for an array, by casting the pointer to the type of the array. To know the type of the array, you need to know the size of the array, at compile time.

Getting the reference to a vector is not possibly using a pointer to an element of the vector.

> to find out the size and other info?

You cannot find out the size of an array with just a single pointer - at least not unless you know something special about the content of that array.

Typically, if an API returns a pointer to an array, it also provides a function to get a pointer to the end of the array (one past last element). If you have both the start and end pointer, you can calculate how many elements are in between.

Another approach is for the API to designate a specific value to represent the end of the array (terminus). This is not very typical for number arrays, since usually all representable values are often needed and cannot be reserved for terminator. This is a very typical way to represent character strings in which the null termination character `'\0'` represents the end of the string. Arrays of pointers that end in `nullptr` are also occasionally used.

Third approach is to somehow provide the size. It could be constant and described in the documentation, or it could be defined by a macro. There could be a function that returns it, or maybe it is a secret that the programmer plans to carry to their grave.

The documentation of the library might describe the chosen approach.